# How can I access the .efi directory of the bios and replace the .efi (specifically BOOTX64.EFI) files?

Tags: windows, bios, uefi, dell-precision

I believe the .efi files are screwed up, some way, some how. When I first got this machine, not long ago, I had no problem booting into a Windows 11 install disk, installing the OS, and had successful subsequent boots for a day or so....

I was getting into enabling virtualization through the bios when I eventually just lost the ability to boot into Windows. The splash screen scrolling circle would freeze and I haven't been able to figure out why.

I eventually got tired of failing to boot so I decided to try Proxmox and see if I could get Windows to boot within a VM, and it did! So to me, that says, there is nothing wrong 'necessarily' with the hardware as proxmox being a type 1 hypervisor Windows is running on bare metal.

Looking back at the 'Add Boot Option' within the Dell bios, and looking at the FS0, the directories look out of place compared to what I saw from a Dell instructional video on youtube about adding Windows Boot Manager back manually.

I tried selecting the 'BOOTX64.EFI' file and associating it with the name 'Windows Boot Manager' and this does not fix my problem.

I think it's narrowed down to some issues with these pre-boot files. Again, I know my way around a computer, but BIOS ain't one of those areas. Please, how can I access these .EFI boot files and replace them with some fresh copies. Also, I don't know what's being used for legacy BIOS booting but MBR Windows install disks don't work either so I'd imagine replacing files associated with that would be needed too.

[image: From Dell's Video]

[image: From my machine]

Comment: I edited this question to remove the “solved” and related notes and adding inline images. Please do not declare a question as “solved.” If there are answers that helped you, please upvote them. If one specific answer solved the question, please just check it off as such. That is what this site is about and how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and safest way to *access* the EFI files is by booting from USB, using an OS such as Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE), or [live Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

You can *view* the EFI files with a disk tool, such as [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/), shown below.

[image: Viewing EFI Files]

On the partition ESP(1), formatted FAT32, there are a number of EFI files in various folders. It is useful, *sometimes*, to modify these files: for example, I worked on one PC that refused to boot Linux unless I renamed the OEM boot files, and then renamed the Ubuntu grubx64.efi as the OEM boot file. While there might have been another work-around, this is easily documented and executed, and easily reversed.

**N.B.** Before making *any* changes to the boot partition, **make an image** so that you can back out any changes. Best is a full disk image, though just the boot partition *might* help recovery. **Without that backup, and error can make your PC unbootable.**

Answer (score 1):

> I tried selecting the 'BOOTX64.EFI' file and associating it with the name 'Windows Boot Manager' and this does not fix my problem.

\EFI\Boot\BootX64.EFI is the "default" location that is likely to be overwritten by whichever OS was installed last – it might be Windows Boot Manager, it might be GRUB, etc. In the `fs0:` volume in your screenshot, it's probably a copy of systemd-boot.efi from Proxmox.

The specific path of Windows Boot Manager is always `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\Bootmgfw.efi`. If that's intact, you can just copy it to BootX64.efi (not that you should *need* BootX64.efi normally).

However, if you get to the "spinning circle" at all, it means the system *did* launch the Windows Boot Manager, and got further than that – it has read its configuration (the BCD file) and you've reached the point of Windows itself being booted. So it's unlikely that these files are the problem.

> Looking back at the 'Add Boot Option' within the Dell bios, and looking at the FS0, the directories look out of place compared to what I saw from a Dell instructional video on youtube about adding Windows Boot Manager back manually.

In your screenshot, the `fs0:` partition looks like what a Linux distribution such as Proxmox would set up. Assuming you're showing contents of the `\EFI` directory, there is no `Microsoft` subdirectory in it (which is where Windows would always put its Boot Manager), so it's certainly not an EFI partition that knows how to boot Windows.

If you have multiple disks connected, each of them (if it has an OS installed) will typically have its own EFI partition, so be sure to take a look at `fs1:` and `fs2:` and so on.

> I think it's narrowed down to some issues with these pre-boot files.
>
> how can I access these .EFI boot files and replace them with some fresh copies

To be clear, there is no "EFI directory of the BIOS". The system firmware itself is not stored in the form of files, and is not being run from any disk or partition – the entirety of it is loaded from dedicated flash storage, and the only way to replace it (or to damage it in the first place) would be to go through the mainboard's "firmware update" process.

In nearly all systems, all of the files found in the "EFI system partition" on your disk are **only** used to boot the actual OS that's installed on that specific disk, or sometimes to start various optional diagnostics and recovery tools. Each disk carries its own EFI boot files for whatever is installed on that disk – your system disk has its own, while your "Windows install" USB stick has its own.

So if you're **not** able to boot into a Windows install CD/USB either, then replacing EFI boot loader files on the system disk will be useless – the bootable CD/USB already brings *its own* EFI boot files (that's why it is "bootable") and the firmware only looks at those when booting from USB.

The install USB stick could have its EFI boot files accidentally deleted, of course, in which case it's easiest to just copy them out of the original Windows ISO (or to rebuild the install USB stick from scratch).

If you **are** able to boot into the Windows install disk and only want to repair the system disk, then `bcdboot` is the command that will re-install the Windows Boot Manager files (from their originals that are kept in C:\Windows or wherever), and will rebuild the "BCD" configuration for Windows Boot Manager as well.

(Each OS has its own boot loader, so each OS will have different commands to repair its boot files; for Linux systems you would use `grub-install` or `bootctl install`. Again, those files have nothing to do with the system firmware itself.)

Once the USB stick has booted, minimize the "install Windows" window, open a console window using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> and use `diskpart` to assign a drive letter to the EFI partition, as well as to find out which drive letter is assigned to the Windows partition (it might not be `C:` in this environment).

```
DISKPART>  list part[ition]
DISKPART>  sel[ect] part[ition] ##
DISKPART>  assign letter=S
DISKPART>  det[ail] vol[ume]
```

(At this point I would actually go to `S:` and clean up the old Windows files first – move the "EFI\Microsoft" directory aside or just delete it completely, as it's about to be rebuilt anyway.)

Once you have the drive letters for both the Windows partition (source) and the EFI partition (target), you can use `bcdboot` to copy fresh Windows Boot Manager files:

```
X:\> bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f UEFI
```

This will create Bootmgfw.efi, add it as an entry to EFI NVRAM, and copy it to BootX64.efi as well. It'll also generate a new BCD config file with a Windows entry for Bootmgfw.efi to use.

(This also works for BIOS-style boot, though it does not write a boot sector – `bootsect` needs to be used for that, separately for the MBR and the VBR.)

Again, to really make it clear, the EFI files on your system disk have no influence on your ability to boot from a USB stick.

> Also, I don't know what's being used for legacy BIOS booting but MBR Windows install disks don't work either so I'd imagine replacing files associated with that would be needed too.

Same answer as above, only more so. The "firmware" parts of the process aren't taken from any file; the entire firmware including its "legacy BIOS emulation" (CSM) module runs directly from the mainboard's write-protected flash.

Though in addition to that, when it comes to BIOS booting, the OS-specific parts of the boot process aren't entirely files either; there is one and often two "boot sectors" that are written to the disk outside of the 'file' area (the MBR for the whole disk, which then jumps to the VBR for the "active" partition).

The MBR is the only thing the firmware cares about when doing BIOS-style boot – any files that are involved in the later stages are entirely at the discretion of the OS-specific VBR found on that disk. (For example, the VBR used by Windows will load the rest of Windows Boot Manager from a file named `\BOOTMGR`.)

For disks with Windows installed (as well as when making Windows install USB sticks), you can use `bootsect` to write both an MBR and a Windows "nt60" VBR. For Linux, `grub-install` takes care of the MBR and the not-quite-VBR that GRUB uses, though some distributions might use Syslinux instead.

Comment: Reset the system firmware ("clear CMOS"); sometimes it helps with the weirdest issues (and with accidentally-changed options). Have you tried selecting "Safe Mode" for Windows boot? Does the system have any additional GPUs or other add-on cards installed? Can you boot from USB if you completely remove all of the fixed disks that are installed?